# How to set autocommit false in apache camel sql batch insertion?

Tags: java, apache-camel, batch-processing, camel-sql

I am using apache-camel sql-batch insertion.
My route for sql batch insertion is as follows:

```
<pipeline>
   <transform>
      <method ref="insertionMyBean" method="myBatchInsertion"></method>
   </transform>
   <choice>
       <when>
           <simple>${in.header.myCount} == ${properties:batch.mySize}</simple>
           <to uri="sql:{{sql.subs.insertMyBatchStatement}}?batch=true"></to>
           <log message="Inserted rows ${body}"></log>
       </when>
   </choice>
</pipeline>
```

I want to configure autocommit false for this route.
Can anybody help me out with this?
FYI...When i use mybatis for batch insertion, autocommit is set false by the mybatis framework. How can i do the same when using plane sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set autocommit in settings of data source (*defaultAutoCommit*).

Answer (score 2):

Camel SQL component uses Spring's JDBC support so the only way to do it (that I know of) would be marking the route as `transacted` - that way the commit would occur once the whole route has completed.